# method newInstance required: int,String[],String[],int found: int,String[],int

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting compiler error for my fragment newInstance, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

When i remove the second array String everything works as expected, but passing another String Array is giving the error:

error: method newInstance in class LightFragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,String[],String[],int
found: int,String[],int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Calling Fragment:

```
`return LightFragment.newInstance(position+1,devicesMacArray,devicesTypeArray, deviceCounter);`
```

and in my Fragment class:

```
`public static LightFragment newInstance(int pageNumber, String[] deviceMac,String[] deviceType, int numOfDevices) {
    LightFragment fragment = new LightFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("PageNumber", pageNumber);
    args.putInt("numberOfDevices", numOfDevices);
    args.putStringArray("deviceMacArray",deviceMac);
    //args.putStringArray("deviceTypeArray",deviceType);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}`
```

I am passing two String Arrays, one has saved Mac addresses and the other the Type of the device.

later to use them within the fragment.

I am able to pass only one String array for some reason, the moment i add the second the compiler provide the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason,

Apparently i had a none used class that calls the same fragment but pass different arguments.

weirdly the android studio did not show an error on that class until i opened it.